# Error when calling SaveChanges() in entity framework 3.5 sp1

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I'm getting the following error when I call the SaveChanges() method on my entity context:

Culture 'en' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture.

My browser culture is set to en-us and so is my OS (tested on windows 7, vista and server 2003).

using(SubscriptionEntity context = new SubscriptionEntity())
            {

```
            User user = new User();
            user.First_Name = firstName;
            user.Last_Name = lastName;
            user.Company = company;
            user.Job_Title = jobTitle;
            user.Email_Address = email;
            user.Address1 = address1;
            user.Date_Created = DateTime.Now;


            User_Mail_Preference_Language_Format user_mail_format_language = new User_Mail_Preference_Language_Format();
            user_mail_format_language.Mail_Preferences_Format = context.Mail_Preferences_Format.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Mail_Preferences_Format_ID == mailFormat);
            user_mail_format_language.Mail_Preferences_Language = context.Mail_Preferences_Language.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Mail_Preferences_Language_ID == languagePreference);
            user.User_Mail_Preference_Language_Format.Add(user_mail_format_language);


            foreach (int i in aoi)
            {
                User_Area_of_Interest user_aoi = new User_Area_of_Interest();
                user_aoi.Area_of_Interest = context.Area_of_Interest.First(p => p.Area_of_Interest_ID == i);
                user.User_Area_of_Interest.Add(user_aoi);
            }

            context.AddToUser(user);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Error:
[NotSupportedException: Culture 'en' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture.]
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CheckNeutral(CultureInfo culture) +7484386
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_NumberFormat() +13
   System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(IFormatProvider formatProvider) +89
   System.Data.EntityUtil.ConvertCardinalityToString(Nullable`1 cardinality) +90
   System.Data.EntityUtil.UpdateRelationshipCardinalityConstraintViolation(String relationshipSetName, Int32 minimumCount, Nullable`1 maximumCount, String entitySetName, Int32 actualCount, String otherEndPluralName, IEntityStateEntry stateEntry) +26
   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.RelationshipConstraintValidator.ValidateConstraints() +417
   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands() +59
   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +210
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache) +117
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptChangesDuringSave) +453
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges() +9
   Osler.PublicWeb.Subscription.Business.Subscription.AddSubscription(String firstName, String lastName, String company, String jobTitle, String email, String address1, String address2, String city, String provinceState, String postalCode, String country, Int32 languagePreference, Int32 mailFormat, List`1 aoi) in D:\DevProjects\OslerDOTcom\Main\Source\Code\Osler.com\Osler.PublicWeb.Subscription.Business\Subscription.cs:150
   osler_ContentTemplates_CT_EmailSubscriptions.SaveSubscriptionInfo() in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\dev.osler.com\osler\ContentTemplates\CT_EmailSubscriptions.ascx.cs:338
   osler_ContentTemplates_CT_EmailSubscriptions.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\dev.osler.com\osler\ContentTemplates\CT_EmailSubscriptions.ascx.cs:38
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton.OnServerClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +109
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Comment: Try to strip your code down to the bare minimun that will reproduce the error and post the code. Also post the full exception message, exception type and stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Bug in Entity Framework](http://devscape.blogspot.com/2010/01/bug-in-entity-framework.html). Entity Framework is seeing your culture as "en"(which is culture neutral) not "en-us"

Comment: I saw that, but I don't have my culture set to 'en'.
I'll try that out to see if it gets rid of the issue.
Thanks!

Comment: I converted the project to .net 4.0 and I ended up figuring it out:  When I submitted the asp.net form, I didn't validate blank values on one field.  The choice was initialized to 0, but the reference table didn't have a value of 0.  .net 4.0 EF gave a different error that helped me narrow down the issue.

Thanks for your help!